# jenkins group of jobs configuration

Tags: jenkins

I have to run few (about 10) jobs in jenkins which differ from each other just with one parameter (github source). The sad thing is sometimes I have to change other parameters and it ends up with changing the same thing ten times. Is it possible to create something like group of jobs where changing one parameter would cause changing parameters in other jobs (included in this group)?

I would be really thankfull for any ideas how to solve this problem.

Sorry - I'm not sure if it's clear - by parameters I mean execute shell command in build section or post-build actions - not a parameter that I have to type/check/whatever before running the job.

Answer (score 1):

I find "Ez-Templates Plugin" much better. There you have much more options to configure.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/ez-templates-plugin

And it has very easy for understanding UI.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer:
You need [Template Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin). With that you can create template with specified build and post-build actions and in projects just check an option "Use builders from another project" where you type the name of the template project. Simple, easy, and you do not need to recreate all projects - you just need to modify them once to use template options.

Answer (score 0):

You may also store the parameter's value in Jenkins global variables (or in the credentials, bound to the Jenkins folder in case you use the Folder plugin). Then edit the value in the single place and it will be available to all jobs that are using it.